# Use variable as key name for model

Tags: python, django

I have the method like this.

```
@classmethod
def get_my_msg(cls):
    return cls.objects.latest("updated_at").my_msg
```

Now , I want to give the variable to function and get the data dynamically such as

```
@classmethod
def get_my_msg(cls,key):
    return cls.objects.latest("updated_at").{key} // use variable here
```

Is it possible?

Comment: i think you already did that by passing key as another argument. But you need to wrap key in braces

Comment: @Irfan wani mmm ,, you mean  like this? `return cls.objects.latest("updated_at").({key})` but it shows `invalid syntax` error as well

Comment: no i mean like this `return cls.objects.latest("updated_at").key`. And sorry, there was a typo in my first comment. I actually wanted to say you don't need to wrap key in braces

Comment: I understand what you mean. I just use brace for example to show what I want.  However, thank you for your comment and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python `gettattr`

```
@classmethod
def get_my_msg(cls,key):
    res = cls.objects.latest("updated_at")
    return getattr(res, key)
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works. `getattr` is very helpful